# There is no registered service of type 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, blazor, httprequest

im trying to do a http Post request in Blazor Server. I try do send a Username and a Password

**this is the Part of the where i do the web Api call:**

```
private IEnumerable<yolo> test = Array.Empty<yolo>();
private bool getBranchesError;
private bool shouldRender;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
     var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
         "https://url.com");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.json");
    request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
    var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        test = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
            <IEnumerable<yolo>>(responseStream);
    }
    else
    {
        getBranchesError = true;
    }

    shouldRender = true;
}
    public class yolo
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Program.cs

```
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
// The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may 
want to change this for production scenarios, 
see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
app.UseHsts();
}  

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();

//http Client
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

I know it's very messy but im already trying 6 hours to solve it :D

**And this is the Error Message**

[image: Error Message]

My goal is that it no longer crashes

If you need more information, just write a comment :D

Comment: Can you show your program.cs re the http client providing.

Comment: You need to register HttpClientFactory in you DI container. Thats precisely what it tells you.

Comment: Don't post code as images, that is frowned upon by the community here at SO. It makes it harder for someone writing an answer to reference your code and it makes it harder for people looking for answers finding your question since the code can't be indexed by search engines.

Comment: Images can't be copied, compiled or tested. By posting an image you're forcing people to type your code just to test it. Very few people will do that

Comment: Same for exceptions. Images can't be googled. Quite often you can find the answer to a problem just by googling the message either the root or an inner exception. The full exception text contains a stack trace of all the calls involved. Again, you can google those snippets to find similar issues

Comment: Can we see your code on `ClientFactory?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you in your `Startup` class do `var app = builder.build();` you implicity say "I'm done registering services". So you need to move your `builder.Services.AddHttpClient();` to somewhere before that line to make it work, it can't be at the end.

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

// Adding services needs to go before this one!
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}  

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```